# Application for windows and mac using python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, build, desktop-application

I'm in a dilemma. I've got a python code that works for each of the yellow squares shown below but I want to make an application that looks like below and uses the information from the first text box and the second drag and drop box. Then depending on what the user clicked on, the code for that would run. I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python GUI libraries like:

1. [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)
2. [PyQT](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt)
3. [WxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/)
4. [Kivy](https://kivy.org/)
5. [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/)

(This list is not exhaustive.)

Each has their own advantages and disadvantages. Choose the one that fits your project the best.

**My personal recommendation for your particular project would be Kivy.**